# Jquery: increment the value of a data attribute for the siblings of an object

Tags: jquery, increment, custom-data-attribute, siblings

How do you increment the value of a data attribute for all of the siblings of an object?

This works:

```
$('#id').data('position')+1
```

but this doesn't

```
$('#id').siblings().data('position') + 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because .siblings() return an array of elements, therefore .data may not work. You have to iterate all element one by one like this

```
$('#id').siblings().each(function(){
   $(this).data('position') + 1; ///
})
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to iterate through siblings

```
var siblings=$('#id').siblings();
siblings.each(function(i,v){
   alert($(this).data('position') + 1);
   //do your stuff
})
```